# Redisson Rollback Operation

Tags: redis, transactions, rollback, redisson

I want to know how the Redisson Library Supports the Rollback operation. What I got from the Redisson Github page is

> Redisson uses locks for write operations and maintains data modification operations list till the commit/rollback operation.

But I am not able to understand how *maintaining data modification operations list till commit/rollback operation* means.

Can anybody please explain to me the working of rollback function in Redisson and how it handles the case when any one of the command throws an exception/error while processing the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Changes applied to Redis only after `commit()` method invocations. On `rollback()` Redisson releases all aquired locks.